# Ionic React - IonRange not showing up properly

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I recently got started with Ionic React and I wanted to experiment with the IonRange component. The following is my IonRange code in JSX (alongside a button and some text):

```
      <IonApp>
            <IonContent>
                <IonGrid className="align-all-center">
                    <IonRow className="content-padding">
                        <IonButton onClick={updateName}>
                            Press Me!
                        </IonButton>
                    </IonRow>
                    <IonRow className="content-padding">
                        <IonText color="light">
                            Hello {name}!
                        </IonText>
                    </IonRow>
                    <IonRow>
                        <IonRange value={50} pin={true} min={0} max={100}></IonRange>
                    </IonRow>
                </IonGrid>
            </IonContent>
      </IonApp>
```

However, the result that I get in my browser is this:

[image: image|180x199]

When ever I try to scrub that dot, one of the values is:

[image: image|269x235]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try putting it in an <IonItem>

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work. Updated code:

Comment: <IonItem>
    <IonRange value={value} pin={true} />
</IonItem>